# $x^2 + 6y^2 = 2807$ no integer solution

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that equation $x^2 + 6y^2 = 2807$ doesn't have solution in the
>   set of integers.

Obviously $x^2$ is odd, so $x$ is odd. Then, I taught that every perfect square has the rest $1$ or $3\bmod 6$, or $0$ or $1\bmod 4$ etc. Knowing this, I should get to a contraction in way or other.

Then, I've looked at $2007$. $2007 = 7 \cdot 401$, so I've taught to take a look at remainders $mod$ $7$ and to take all the cases for $x$ ($7k+1, 7k+2, 7k+3,\ldots$). But it didn't work.

Comment: **Hint:** Analyze it modulo $6$.

Comment: @Lucian modulo $3$ is enough.

Comment: @user236182: Why aim for less when you can aim for more ? :-$)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since $6y²$ is even, we know that $x²$ and thus x are odd. Then you easily find $6y²=2807-x²$. Now that that equation mod 6. You have $0=5-x² \mod 6$. Since $x$ is odd you find by testing that $x² \mod 6=1$ or $ 3$.In both cases it is not 5, so the equation have no integer solutions.

P.S: You should be a little bit more friendly when asking questions, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, $2807 = 7 \cdot 401.$ There is no problem with the prime $7,$ but Legendre symbol $(-24|401)= -1.$ The elementary lemma, actually works for any form when written properly, anyway, if $$ u^2 + 6 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {401}, $$ then both $u,v$ are divisible by $401.$